# Facing an issue with back button click event using history.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, history.js

I have implemented State Aware URL on ajax call using history.js(using pushState method). Now when I click back button of any browser, it should load content of previous state using my ajax method.For this I have done following:

```js
$(function () {
    // history.js 
    History.Adapter.bind(window, 'statechange', function () {
        var State = History.getState();
        callAjax(State.data.loadUrl);
    });
});
```

But this code executes on every state change as well as on forward/backward. I just want to execute it on the forward / backward event of any browser. What shall I do to get this?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way in History.js to know when the back button was pressed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8211068/is-there-a-way-in-history-js-to-know-when-the-back-button-was-pressed)

Comment: Thank you for your response. But I have tried with it already and it is not working. Can you please explain that answer? Because in that initially sets the value for manualStateChange and then checked for the same. Why so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done following:

```
$(function () {
// history.js
History.Adapter.bind(window, 'statechange', function () {
    if (manualStateChange == true) {
        var State = History.getState();
        callAjax(State.data.loadUrl);
    }
    manualStateChange = true;
});});
```

And when I change the satate of URL I set the value :

> manualStateChange = false;

If I set true value for manualStateChange in jquery function then on every state change it calls the function. That's why I have removed that line from my code and it works for me.